# Header e Footer com ASP. Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, template, microsoft

Estou com duvida para separar meu codigo,fiz alguns testes de ter separado o header e footer mas no visual studio fiz que só pode ter somente uma <% Page, como posso separar o header e o footer e juntar em um só

Comment: Não pode usar as tags do `html5`,  `header` e `footer`?

Comment: posso,mas eu quero dividir em arquivos diferentes e depois chamar eles para todas pages que eu quero usar

Answer (score 0):

Em ASP .Net você não inclui páginas, como se faz em PHP, você tem q criar uma Layout page, que é uma página completa, tanto com o Helder como o footer, e sua página vai ser um fragmento dentro dessa Layout page.